# php error + mysqli a noticed error

Tags: php, mysql, forms

i ama getting an error  that say

**Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\chat2\ajaxLoad.php on line 15**

i do not know how to solve this can anyone help me ???

## this is the code

```
<?php
 require_once('mysqli.class.php');  

$config = array();
        $config['host'] = 'localhost';
        $config['user'] = 'root';
        $config['pass'] = 'root';
        $config['table'] = 'messages';

        $db = new DB($config);

        // Run a Query:
        $db->query('SELECT * FROM message');

        echo$db->get();



?>
```

Comment: Where is the definition of `DB`?

Comment: user print_r($db->get()); instead of echo $db->get();

Comment: no the database called messages  and the table called message

Comment: the definition of the DB class is in the including file

Comment: `var_dump($db->get());` to see what your `$db->get()` really returns :)

Answer (score 1):

`$db->get()` returns an array. An array is a list of things. `echo` can only print strings and numbers, not arrays, so it does not know what to do with it. It prints `Array` and gives this notice.

If you want to print the whole array, use

```
print_r($db->get());
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because whatever comes out of `$db->get()` is an array and not a string, but when you try to echo it, PHP will attempt to convert it; hence the notice.

You could use `print_r()` or `var_dump()` instead:

```
print_r($db->get());
```

To iterate over the results:

```
foreach ($db->get() as $row) {
    // do something with $row, also an array most likely
}
```